# How can I make this question more clear?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unclear

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134776/why-is-my-c-sharp-application-executing-code-that-doesnt-belong-to-any-modules

I'm not sure how I can make this question more clear, or exactly what is wrong with it.

I think I'm asking a pretty explicit question: I want to know why my C# applications regularly execute instructions at locations that don't fall within any module's address space, and how I can figure out where these instructions came from.

What is wrong with this question? How can I further simplify what I'm asking?

Comment: The first comment there nailed it: Your question is (still) missing all the details neccessary to answer it.

Comment: Sorry, but you know *what code is being executed*, or you wouldn't know that your application is *executing code that doesn't belong to any module's address space*.

Comment: I have a set of 20 instructions that are executing, including local jumps _to other instructions that don't map to any module's address space_, and calls to `mscorlib` that can't be resolved to functions. This is all irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 6):

This is what your question could be summarized to in its current form:

> I've got some code that does weird things. Looks legit, but weird. What could possibly cause that?

You've been asked repeatedly in the comments to provide details. Please do that. At the very least, give a **concrete** example for the behavior you're witnessing, with the relevant data from your debugger's views and the snippet of your code that is exhibiting this strange behavior. And if you can provide an MCVE, all the better.

Moderns VM+JIT+huge library environments are complex beasts, the number of reasons why the could do things that appear "weird" is phenomenal. Tell us about your specific situation.

Here's another view on why providing a concrete example would help: if someone wants to provide an answer right now, you've let them do all the work, including reproducing the issue you're alluding to. If you had a simple example set up, at least that part would be out of the way and they could focus on explaining what is happening, why it is happening, and perhaps extend to other examples where the same sort of thing occurs.

Comment: Where in my question do I mention 'weird' behavior or ask about the behavior I'm witnessing? I'm asking a question about a low level detail of the CLR, not a specific scenario.

Comment: Read the last sentence in my post again. If you want to know all the reasons why the C# runtime environment might appear to do strange things, that's way too broad. You found a concrete example where you don't understand the behavior, ask about that. Chances are you'll get a bit more than just the answer for that specific scenario if you get a good answer. But to get any answer at all, narrow it down.

Comment: This is a non-issue now, because I referred a colleague from Microsoft to my post, and __he knew exactly what I was referring to__. It's sad that StackOverflow has devolved to this point.

Comment: Good for you, good of him. Now your [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293790/how-can-i-make-this-question-more-clear/293798?noredirect=1#comment190878_293790)  contains more information about the issue you're seeing than your question. What exactly is your issue with adding more details about your specific problem in your question? You have it at hand already.

Comment: No, my question has all of the information needed for anyone with expertise in the problem domain to answer it, as I've demonstrated, and I commented that same information hours ago. Just because you don't understand the domain isn't a reason to close a question.

Comment: You asked for advice about why your question was being ill-received. I gave you advice as to what I think the reason is, based on my experience here and the comments others have posted. If you don't want to follow that advice, fine, do as you please. But I'm not sure I see the point of this meta question if you don't intend to adapt your post at all.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Ah, yes. the "that *one* expert understood my question right away" defense. It won't help you. For a question to be fit for SO, people who have professional experience in the technology **but who are not experts in it** must be able to see the relationship between the question and the answer. When I have enough expertise to figure out an answer to a question posted on SO which is as cryptic as yours, the first thing I do is rewrite the question for a broader audience. If you can rewrite it like that, you may be able to save it.

Comment: For clarification and explanation, could you please tell us what it was that your MS colleague knew exactly from the details you provided to SO?  Where did we go wrong?  What did we miss?